# Using change() to add up total cost from radio button groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

I'm building a card ordering site that's selected through radio button groups. I came up with this to add a total cost. I got the base card price working but when i added additional costs seemingly using the same logic I can't seem to figure out a working total add up function.

PS- Sorry for the mess of a post

I've added console logs to find errors but none show up when going through the process.

```
// create a variables

var selectedCardPricePer;
var cardOneQty;
var cardOneCombinedPricePer;
var cardOneSubtotal;
let paperType;
let envType;
let totalPricePer;

// Get base price based on selected card
$('input:radio[name="img-select"]').change(
    function() {
        // select the checked radio button, grab the "ratio" attribute, and save it as "selectedCardType"
        var selectedCardType = $('input:radio[name="img-select"]:checked').attr('ratio');
        console.log('selectedCardType = %s', selectedCardType);

        // BASE PRICES
        // grab the price for the price per card depending on the selected card type 
        if (selectedCardType == '5x7') {
            selectedCardPricePer = 0.10; // price per 5x7 card
        } else if (selectedCardType == '7x5') {
            selectedCardPricePer = 0.15; // price per 7x5 card
        } else if (selectedCardType == '4x8p5') {
            selectedCardPricePer = 0.00; // price per 4x8.5 calendar card
        } else if (selectedCardType == '8p5x4') {
            selectedCardPricePer = 0.00; // price per 8.5x4 calendar card
        } else {
            console.log('selectedCardType = %s', selectedCardType);
            console.log('selectedCardType does not have an associated price!');
        }

        console.log('selectedCardPricePer = %s', selectedCardPricePer);
        // "selectedCardPricePer" should be relevant per the selected card 
    }
);

// create the paper price variable
var addPricePerPaper = 0;

// paper prices
$('input:radio[name="paper-select"]').change(
    function() {
        var selectedPaper;

        // select the checked radio button, grab the "ratio" attribute, and save it as "selectedCardType"
        var selectedPaper = $('input:radio[name="paper-select"]:checked').val();
        console.log('selectedPaper = %s', selectedPaper);

        // grab the price for the price per card depending on the selected card type 
        if (selectedPaper == 'Premium Paper') {
            addPricePerPaper = 0.10; // price per premium
        } else if (selectedPaper == 'Standard Paper') {
            addPricePerPaper = 0; // price per standard
        } else {
            console.log('selectedPaper does not equal an appropriate value');
        }

        console.log('addPricePerPaper = %s', addPricePerPaper);
        // 'addPricePerPaper' should be relevant per the selected paper.
    }
);

// create the envelope price variable
var addPricePerEnvelope = 0;

// env prices
$('input:radio[name="env-select"]').change(
    function() {
        // select the checked radio button, grab the value.
        var selectedEnvelope = $('input:radio[name="env-select"]:checked').attr('material');
        console.log('selectedEnvelope = %s', selectedEnvelope);

        // grab the price for the price per card depending on the selected card type 
        if (selectedEnvelope == 'standard') {
            addPricePerEnvelope = 0; // price per 
        } else if (selectedEnvelope == 'linen') {
            addPricePerEnvelope = 0.10; // price per 
        } else if (selectedEnvelope == 'foil') {
            addPricePerEnvelope = 0.15; // price per
        } else if (selectedEnvelope == 'none') {
            addPricePerEnvelope = 0; // price per
        } else {
            console.log('selectedEnvelope did not equal an appropriate value');
        }

        console.log('addPricePerEnvelope = %s', addPricePerEnvelope);

        // addPricePerEnvelope should equal the extra price per envelope
    }
);

var addPricePerPrintedReturn = 0;

// Create the printed return price variable
$('input:checkbox[name="env-printed-return"]').change(
    function() {

        // set the variable to false first, in case it is not checked
        var checkedReturn = false;

        // check if the checkbox is checked, if so, this sets the variable to true
        checkedReturn = $('input:checkbox[name="env-printed-return"]').prop('checked');
        console.log('checkedReturn = %s', checkedReturn);

        // if the variable is true, add a price, if not, don't.
        if (checkedReturn == true) {
            addPricePerPrintedReturn = 0.05;
        } else {
            addPricePerPrintedReturn = 0;
        }
        console.log('addPricePerPrintedReturn = %s', addPricePerPrintedReturn);

        // addPricePerPrintedReturn should equal the extra price per return address addition
    }
)

/*
    Up to this point, we should have several variables set per the following:
    - selectedCardPricePer = base price per card
    - addPricePerPaper = extra price per card, for a paper option
    - addPricePerEnvelope = extra price per env, for a env option
    - addPricePerPrintedReturn = extra price to print return addresses on envs, if selected
*/

// watch qty
$('input[name="quantity-field-one"]').change(
    function () { 
        // grab the quantity
        cardOneQty = $('input[name="quantity-field-one"]').val();
    }
);


// I'll need to come back to this
$('input:radio[name="img-select"]').change(updateCardOnePricing());
$('input:radio[name="paper-select"]').change(updateCardOnePricing());
$('input:radio[name="env-select"]').change(updateCardOnePricing());
$('input:checkbox[name="env-printed-return"]').change(updateCardOnePricing());
$('input[name="quantity-field-one"]').change(updateCardOnePricing());

// Update Pricing Function
function updateCardOnePricing() {

    console.log('updateCardOnePricing triggered.');

    console.log('selectedCardPricePer = %s', selectedCardPricePer);
    console.log('addPricePerPaper = %s', addPricePerPaper);
    console.log('addPricePerEnvelope = %s', addPricePerEnvelope);
    console.log('addPricePerPrintedReturn = %s', addPricePerPrintedReturn);
    console.log('cardOneQty = %s', cardOneQty);

    // add up the total cost per card
    cardOneCombinedPricePer = selectedCardPricePer + addPricePerPaper + addPricePerEnvelope + addPricePerPrintedReturn;
    console.log('cardOneCombinedPricePer = %s', cardOneCombinedPricePer);

    // combine the quantity with price to get subtotal
    cardOneSubtotal = cardOneQty * cardOneCombinedPricePer;
    console.log('cardOneSubtotal = %s', cardOneSubtotal);

    // round to nearest tenth
    cardOneSubtotal = Number(Math.round(cardOneSubtotal+'e2')+'e-2');
    // fix deicmals to make sense for monies
    cardOneSubtotal = cardOneSubtotal.toFixed(2);

    $('#card1-subtotal').html(cardOneSubtotal);
}
```

///// HTML Below

```
<div class="radio-button">
                        <input type="radio" name="paper-select" id="paper-opt1" value="Standard Paper" checked="checked" />
                        <label material="Standard">
                            Standard paper
                        </label>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="radio-button">
                        <input type="radio" name="paper-select" id="paper-opt2" value="Premium Paper" material="Premium" />
                        <label >
                        Premium (+ $0.10 per)
                        </label>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <span class="step-label">
                        Envelope Options
                    </span>

                    <div class="radio-button">
                        <input type="radio" name="env-select" id="env-opt1" value="No Envelope" material="none" />
                        <label >
                            No Envelope
                        </label>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="radio-button">
                        <input type="radio" name="env-select" id="env-opt2" value="Standard Non-Printed Envelope" material="standard" checked="checked"/>
                        <label >
                            Standard Non-Printed Envelope (+ $0.00 per)
                        </label>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="radio-button">
                        <input type="radio" name="env-select" id="env-opt3" value="Linen Envelope" material="linen"/>
                        <label >
                            Linen Envelope (+ $0.10 per)
                        </label>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="radio-button">
                        <input type="radio" name="env-select" id="env-opt4" value="Foil-Lined Envelope" material="foil"/>
                        <label >
                            Foil-Lined Envelope (+ $0.15 per)
                        </label>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="radio-button">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="env-printed-return" id="env-opt5" value="Printed Return Address" material="return"/>
                        <label >
                            Printed Return Address (+ $0.05 per)
                        </label>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="p under">
                    <label for="quantity-field-one">
                        <span class="step-label">
                            Quantity:
                        </span>
                        <input type="number" name="quantity-field-one" id="quantity-field-one" required>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                    </label>


                    <div class="subtotal">
                        <p>
                            Price per card 
                            <strong>
                                $
                                <span id="card1-ppc">
                                    <em>Please select a card.</em>
                                </span> <!-- price per card appended here -->
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="total">
                        <p>
                            Subtotal
                            <strong>
                                $
                                <span id="card1-subtotal">
                                    <em>Please enter a quantity.</em>
                                </span> <!-- price subtotal for this card appended here -->
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are radio buttons generated dynamically on the flow? If yes when and how are they added?

Comment: They are not dynamically generated they're just groups in the html.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your HTML showing a sample radio button group code?

Comment: Yep, I've added the html with radio button groups that when I added functions through me off.

Answer (score 0):

When handling an event on multiple elements with same name/class you should use the keyword 'this' to refer to the element inside the function otherwise you are always referring the first element of the collection. You have same issue with all the event handlers.

So basically this:

```
$('input:radio[name="img-select"]').change(
    function() {
        // select the checked radio button, grab the "ratio" attribute, and save it as "selectedCardType"
        var selectedCardType = $('input:radio[name="img-select"]:checked').attr('ratio');
```

should look like this:

```
$('input:radio[name="img-select"]').change(
    function() {
        // select the checked radio button, grab the "ratio" attribute, and save it as "selectedCardType"
        var selectedCardType = $(this).attr('ratio');
```

in all your event handlers.

Notice the use of $(this) to refer to the current element, not always the first.